# Asana: Adding a task to a project section while creating it

Tags: api, curl, asana, asana-api, asana-connect

I am trying to add a task on a particular section of a project using Asana API. I have tried the membership object with project and section id specified in the following doc.

[Asana api doc](https://asana.github.io/developer_docs_prerelease/api_reference/#operation/createTask)

But it's throwing 404 when I run the api call. What am I doing wrong? Please take a look in the json I am using.

```
    "projects": [ "121212121" ],
    "memberships": [
        {
           "project": {
             "id": "121212121",
             "gid": "121212121",
             "name": "test"
           },
           "section": {
             "id": "090909090",
             "gid": "090909090",
             "name": "test"
           }
        }
    ]
```

I have tried this JSON too

```
    "projects": [ "121212121" ],
    "memberships": [{
        "project": "121212121",
        "section" : "090909090"
    }]
```

However I am unable to see this option memberships in the following documentation.

[Asana developer doc](https://developers.asana.com/docs/create-a-task)

Do I have to add the task to the project section after creating it using separate API call?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issues with the create task method in the client library.  THe memberships should look like the following:

```
'memberships':[       
  {
   'project': guid (as a string),
   'section': guid (as a string)
  }     
]
```